# Deligne's formula

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, quasicoherent-sheaves

Let $M$ be some $A$-module and $f \in A$. Why do we have an isomorphism
$$\varinjlim_n \hom_A(f^n A,M) \cong M_f \text{ ?}$$
*Background*. Let $X$ be a scheme, $U$ an open subscheme, and $F,G$ quasi-coherent sheaves on $X$. There is a canonical homomorphism
$$\varinjlim_{J \subseteq \mathcal{O}_X , J|_{U} = \mathcal{O}_U} \hom_{\mathcal{O}_X}(JF,G)  \to \hom_{\mathcal{O}_U}(F|_U,G|_U).$$
Deligne has shows that this is an isomorphism when $X$ is noetherian and $F$ is of finite type (see EGA I (1970), Prop. 6.9.17). In particular, we have the following explicit description of the quasi-coherent sheaf $\tilde{M}$ on $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ for a noetherian ring $A$ and some $A$-module $M$:
$$\tilde{M}(U) = \varinjlim_{J \subseteq A, \tilde{J}|_U = \mathcal{O}_U} \hom_A(J,M)$$
Note that, when $U$ is the complement of $V(I)$, the condition $\tilde{J}|_U = \mathcal{O}_U$ means $I \subseteq \sqrt{J}$, or equivalently $I^n \subseteq J$ for some $n$. This gives an even more explicit formula
$$\tilde{M}(\mathrm{Spec}(A) \setminus V(I)) = \varinjlim_n \hom_A(I^n,M).$$
In the [paper](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927879208824463) "Sections of quasi-coherent sheaves" it is claimed that this formula also holds when $U$ is a basic-open subset i.e. $I$ is principal and $A$ is not assumed to be noetherian. But I cannot prove this. The colimit becomes
$$\cong \varinjlim_n ~\hom_A(f^n A,M) \cong \varinjlim_n ~\{m \in M : \mathrm{Ann}(f^n) \subseteq \mathrm{Ann}(m)\}.$$
The transition maps multiply with $f$. This colimit has a canonical injection to $\varinjlim_n ~ M \cong M_f = \tilde{M}(D(f))$. But I don't see why it should be surjective. Even when $A$ is noetherian, I don't see a direct argument, without repeating Deligne's proof (which essentially uses the Artin-Rees Lemma).

Comment: Theorem 2.2.16, Brodmann and Sharp, *Local Cohomology*.

Comment: I don't have access to this book, and some (essential) pages in the google preview are missing. Could you please sketch the argument? I think it has to be very simple ...

Comment: Brodmann and Sharp suppose all rings to be noetherian. However, their proof works if $A$ has the property that the $f$-torsion functor preserves injectivity of $A$-modules.

Comment: I also expect that it doesn't hold if $A$ is arbitrary. Somehow I find errors in published papers every day (why?!). And this is not a pedantic one, since the authors really emphasize that, whereas the general case is treated by Deligne for noetherian rings, the case of basic open sets holds for arbitrary rings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is worked out for finitely generated ideals $I \subset A$ in [Lemma Tag 01PM](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01PM) with a counter example to your question when $I$ is generated by $2$ elements in [Example Tag 01PN](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01PN). Moreover, there it is shown that the correct thing is to look at the system of modules $\text{Hom}_A(I^n, M/M_n)$ where $M_n = M[I^n]$ is the $I^n$-torsion of $M$.

To get a counter example for one element, we could try the ring $A = k[x, y, z_1, z_2, \ldots]/(x^i z_i)$ and module $M = A$. Then the element $y/x$ of $M_x = \widetilde{M}(D(x))$ doesn't seem to be in the image. Namely, any corresponding map $I^n = (x^n) \to A$ should send $x^n$ to $x^{n - 1} y$, I think. But $x^n$ is annihilated by $z_n$ whereas $x^{n - 1} y$ is not.

OK? I will try to add this to the example in the Stacks project.

Comment: Corresponding change in Stacks project can be found here: https://github.com/stacks/stacks-project/commit/0ec01b1ed5681325cbb99f45bae3e79174e28403.